# How to Connect with Dockerized Apollo GraphQL API

Tags: docker, networking, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

I'm moving some of my applications to Docker and I'm having some trouble configuring networking between them. Here's the basic layout of my application currently. I'm having difficulty connecting the API of my application (an Apollo GraphQL Server) and the frontend (React using Apollo Client).

Currently, I'm sending all traffic coming through on Port 80 to a Docker container (React App Nginx) that's serving up my pre-built react application. Pretty straightforward.

That application contains a configuration for the ApolloClient that should create an HttpLink with my backend Server, with `process.env.REACT_APP_API` pointing to it.

[image: My current architecture]

The `REACT_APP_API` variable is baked into the Javascript that a user will download into their browser. When the user's browser makes a POST request to a specific endpoint, I'll need to ensure that they are pointed at the backend. How can I configure this architecture so that the Apollo Client, which is getting served up to users in one container, can connect to the API, which is running in another container?

I could expose that API at `http://localhost:3000/graphql` for example, or could somehow connect the two over Docker's bridge network...? The API is using [apollo-server-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-server-express).

Here's the Dockerfile for my Frontend:

```
FROM node:14 AS builder
LABEL maintainer="kingofcramers.dev@gmail.com"
WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install

COPY tsconfig.json .eslintrc.js .stylelintrc.json .env.production .
COPY src ./src
COPY public ./public
RUN npm run prod:build

###########
## NGINX ##
###########

FROM nginx:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN rm -rf ./*

# Copy built assets from builder stage into html folder for Nginx to serve
COPY --from=builder /app/build .

# Expose app on port 80...
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And for my backend:

```
FROM node:14
LABEL maintainer="kingofcramers.dev@gmail.com"
WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install

COPY tsconfig.json modules.d.ts .
COPY src ./src
RUN npm run prod:build

CMD ["node", "build/index.js"]
```

Comment: In the diagram, does the "React App (Nginx)" component forward requests to the "API Container" directive (something like `proxy_pass http://api:3000`)?  If so, can you just configure the backend URL to `/graphql`, with no host part?

Comment: I've added the Dockerfiles so that you can see them—I'm not currently configuring the nginx.conf file at all, I'm just using Nginx to serve up the files through the `/usr/share/nginx/html` folder. Would that be necessary to setup this kind of a configuration?

Comment: I've tried passing "/graphql" as my uri, and I'm getting "Invariant Violation: 29" error, which suggests that I'm not providing the client correctly. But this setup works in development...?